# Access denied even after IAM permissions are given for Startexportask

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am trying to create a script which creates snapshot and export it using startexporttask operation.The following IAM permissions are configured as shown in screeshot.Even after the needed configuration along with s3 putobject permissions and MFA credentials are set ,access denied error is thrown

```
  import boto3  import datetime
    # Set up client for RDS 
    rds = boto3.client('rds')
    # Set up client for S3 
    s3 = boto3.client('s3') 
    # Set the name of the specific database
     db_name = "test-db-rds"
    # Set the name of the S3 bucket 
    s3_bucket = "s3-dev-rds-export"
    # Set the prefix for the exported snapshot in S3 
    s3_prefix = "snapshots/"
    # Set the IAM role ARN for the export task
    #role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/rds-s3-export" 
    # Set the KMS key ID for the export task
    # kms_key = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:1234567890:key/12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890"
    # Get the current date and time 
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Construct the snapshot name
     RDS_s3_snapshot = db_name + "-" + now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
    # Create a snapshot of the specific database 
    snapshot = rds.create_db_snapshot(DBSnapshotIdentifier=RDS_s3_snapshot, DBInstanceIdentifier=db_name)
    # Get the ARN of the snapshot
     snapshot_arn = snapshot['DBSnapshot']['DBSnapshotArn']
    # Export the snapshot to S3
rds.start_export_task(ExportTaskIdentifier=RDS_s3_snapshot, S3BucketName=s3_bucket, SourceArn=snapshot_arn, IamRoleArn='', S3Prefix=s3_prefix, ExportOnly=db_name)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNQGC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmJpb.png)

Can snapshot resource in startexporttask action be given with specific snapshot_name ,in this case it is RDS_s3_snapshot instead of snapshot:*

Comment: See [export troubleshooting](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-export-snapshot/).

Comment: @jarmod  Role cannot able to have  "Resource: *" (full access) as per the doc you shared.
Can you let me know with minimum permissions how the exportstarttask action can be performed

Comment: You should post the text of your full IAM policy (and not as an image). Be sure you have the requisite S3, RDS, and IAM GetRole/PassRole permissions and any needed KMS permissions. One debugging option is to allow service:* on resource * for S3, RDS, IAM, KMS temporarily and test it works, then pare down the policy to the minimum.

Comment: Thank you @jarmod.The error is resolved by giving resource* in start_export_task.

Comment: @jarmod We need the data to be exported in .sql format and in parquet .The default is parquet. Please let me know whether you could help

Comment: RDS export always produces parquet format data afaik. You will need another backup/export mechanism to generate .sql output, for example using mysqldump (if this is a MySQL database), or find a tool to convert parquet to .sql.